# Confused with objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Ruby Newbie here,

I understand that everything is an object in Ruby, one thing that I wasn't sure about was understanding Variables. Variables basically give reference to objects (correct me if I'm wrong). During an instructional video, the teacher did a demonstration which went as below:

(irb)

```
a = 100
==> 100
b = a
==> 100
b
==> 100
```

This part I get, makes total sense.

Then he did

```
a = 50
==> 50
b
==> 100
```

If B is supposed to point to what a was set which was a 100, why does b still point to 100 if a has now been set as 50?

Comment: I guess the first assignment to a should be 100?

Comment: @Lennart Koopmann, my thought as well, I corrected it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the cool thing, `100` is an object too. So `a` pointed to the constant object `100` and when you assigned `b = a` you assigned `b` to the pointer to the object `100` not to the pointer for `a` or even a value of 100 held by `a`.

To see this is true try this:

```
irb> puts 100.object_id
=> 201
```

Cool huh?

Here's a little explanation of the Ruby object model I wrote up a while back. It's not specific to your question but adds a little more knowledge on how the Ruby object model works:

When you create an instance of an object what you have created is a new object with a set of instance variables and a pointer to the class of the object (and a few other things like an object ID and a pointer to the superclass) but the methods themselves are not in the instance of the object. The class definition contains the list of methods and their code (and a pointer to its own class, a pointer to its superclass, and an object ID).

When you call a method on an instance Ruby looks up the class of the instance and looks in that class's method list for the method you called. If it doesn't find it then it looks in the class' superclass. If it doesn't find it there it looks in that class' superclass until it runs out of superclasses. Then it goes back to the first class and looks for a method_missing method. If it doesn't find one it goes to the superclass and so on till it gets to the root object where it's designed to raise an error.

Let's say for instance you have a class Person and you make an instance of the class with the variable bubba like this:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :dob, :name
  def age
    years = Time.now.year - @dob.year
    puts "You are #{years} year#{"s" if years != 1} old"
  end
  def feed
    puts "nom, nom, nom"
  end
end
bubba = Person.new
bubba.name = "Bubba"
bubba.dob = Time.new(1983,9,26)
```

The class diagram would look something like this:
[image]

So what's happening when you create a static method, a class/module method? Well, remember that almost everything is an object in Ruby and a module definition is an instance of the class Class. Yep, that code you type out is actually an instance too, it's live code. When you create a class method by using def self.method_name you are creating a method in the instance of the object that is the class/module definition.

Great, so where's that class method being defined at you ask? It's being defined in an anonymous class (aka singleton, eigen, ghost class) that is created for exactly this reason.

Going back to our Person class what if we add a class method on the instance bubba like so:

```
def bubba.drive_pickup
  puts "Yee-haw!"
end
```

That method gets put into a special singleton class created just for that instance and the singleton's superclass is now the Person class. This makes our method calling chain look like this:
[image]

Any other methods defined on the instance object bubba will also be put into that singleton class. There's never more than one singleton class per instance object.

So, to wrap it all up the reason why it doesn't work is the static methods in the modules are being defined in the singleton class for the instance of the module definition. When you include or extend from the module you are adding a pointer to the method table of the module but not the method table of the instance object of the singleton class for the module.

Think of it this way: If you create an instance x of type Z and an instance y of type Z should x know about y? No, not unless specifically told about it. So too your module that mixes in another module should not know about some other object that just happens to have that first module as its superclass.

For a much better explanation of the Ruby object model watch this awesome free video by the amazingly erudite [Dave Thomas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Thomas_(programmer)) (no, not the guy from Wendy's):
http://scotland-on-rails.s3.amazonaws.com/2A04_DaveThomas-SOR.mp4

After watching that video I bought Dave Thomas's whole [series on the Ruby object model](http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming) from Pragmatic and it was well worth it.

P.S. Anyone please feel free to correct me on anything I forgot; like what's specifically in an object.

Comment: WOW thanks a lot! The first paragraph just resonated completely and I got it. Going to check out that video

Answer (score 2):

b = a does not mean: b equals a. It means : let b refer to the same object that a is referring to now.
If you later decide to refer a to another object

```
a=50
```

then b still refers to the old object.

It's like you have a dog and decide to name it Charles (Charles = a Dog). Later on, you also use the name Charlie for the dog. (Charlie = Charles). The dog doesn't mind how many names refer to him, it's the same old dog.

Still later you get a goldfish and you decide Charles is a much better name for a goldfish than for a dog (Charles =  a Goldfish). In Ruby, the dog is now still named Charlie.

Mind you, if the dog has no name at all, he'll get garbage collected eventually.

Comment: +1 You rounded out the explanation by clarifying you assign pointers not values.

Comment: And the best thing, you could dynamically change the dog's attributes so he looks like a parrot. But only if we can watch.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that variables refer to (or hold) *values*, not references to other variables.  So when you assign `b = a` you're saying "let b hold the value that a currently holds".  So "a" and "b" are separate variables that happen to hold the same reference.  You can change either one without affecting the other.